# Why are wireless networks that work for other people super slow on my Lenovo Yoga?

Tags: wireless

I am helping a friend troubleshoot her new Lenovo Yoga 2, running a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04. She's getting kicked off of wireless networks a lot, and her connection is super slow. I'm running 14.04 on a Lenovo X1 and using the same wireless network and not having any trouble.

When I run `nm-tool` I see (among other things):

```
Capabilities:
   Speed:           54 Mb/s
```

She sees:

```
Capabilities:
   Speed:           9 Mb/s
```

Similarly, `iwconfig` shows a much slower connection for her:

```
hilary@hilary:~$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"Young Turnip"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 00:22:6B:87:D6:6B   
          Bit Rate=11 Mb/s   Tx-Power=16 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=34/70  Signal level=-76 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:1  Invalid misc:126   Missed beacon:0
```

I see `Bit Rate=54 Mb/s` when I run `iwconfig`.

I spotted this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/387922/slow-wireless-connection-on-lenovo But I'm not clear on what he's actually disabling there.

Per [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425205#425205), here are the full diagnostics: [script results](http://paste.debian.net/106728)

How do we troubleshoot this?

Comment: Why is this flagged as too broad? I realize I need help narrowing down the problem, but it is a very real problem that is making it very hard for her to run Ubuntu.

Comment: Sunspots? You're connecting to an 802.11B WAP? You're too far away from the WAP?

Comment: We're connected to the same wireless network, it works fine for me and is absurdly slow for her. We're sitting a foot apart.

Comment: Too broad because "why is foo slow?" is too broad. To narrow things down requires discussion, and Ask Ubuntu is not a discussion forum (Ubuntu Forums would be a good place to discuss perhaps). A single WAP can provide support for a broad range of 802.11 wireless specifications. B is rated around 11 MB/s and G is 54 MB/s. A WAP may provide A/B/G/N access, and one laptop might connect to N, with another to B.

Comment: The question you've found, slow wireless on lenovo, might be spot on. Try the first command to see if disabling 11n makes a difference. If it helps, the second one will make the change permanent.

Comment: @mikewhatever now it just won't connect at all. Tries, disconnects. Over and over.

Comment: I see. A reboot should get you back to the original settings. If you do want to troubleshoot it, post a thread on the http://ubuntuforums.org, it is more suitable for back and forth exchange, and I hope we'll be able to help.

Comment: @mikewhatever Actually, [UbuntuForums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2231431&s=19977b3f35864d02f60f92f132d5756a&p=13058430#post13058430) isn't much help either.

Comment: You're not supposed to need to do this, but it does help my wireless.  Enter the command `sudo iw reg set US` - this is temporary, until the next reboot.

Comment: @Amanda did you solve this? I have the same problem: [Wireless card unstable on Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro](http://askubuntu.com/q/517463) What was inside the (deleted) answer you posted?

Comment: @rubo77 Still having issues, sadly.

Comment: @Amanda Is this still an issue?

Answer (score 0):

1. Maybe it make a difference if you disable the power save options with:

   ```
   sudo iw dev wlan0 set power_save off
   ```
2. Also you can try if it makes a difference if you disable the 11n extension with the following:

   ```
   sudo su
   echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" >> /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
   ```

   You need to reboot after this.

You can monitor the speed with

```
 watch -d -c "sudo nm-tool |grep -i speed "
```