# List all kernel settings to get details about installed devices

Tags: wireless, kernel

How can I find out with which settings my kernel was compiled?

I would like to understand the concept behind this. I wonder how I can find out which device uses which module.

**For example:** right now, I want to find out which which wifi module my kernel is running because it is my [Intel Corporation Wireless-N 7260 card dies randomly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/517463/wireless-card-unstable-on-lenovo-yoga-2-pro?noredirect=1#comment709078_517463)

I tried: `make menuconfig` but this just shows:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `menuconfig'.  Stop.
```

Or can I find out the module with sysctl? [This is the output of `sysctl -a`](https://gist.github.com/rubo77/269ed36d330ceac1ed04)

Comment: Notice that the kernel was probably compiled with *gazillion* wifi modules. You should check which wifi module is loaded, with `lsmod`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't really help to understand the concept to look at the kernel settings:

```
cat /boot/config-`uname -r`
```

This only shows which settings were used, while the kernel was compiled and unless you want to compile your own kernel, there is now use to change this.

You want to look at the output of `lsmod`, which shows all loaded modules. There you can **guess**, which module could be used for which device, In this example it is something with "iw:

```
$ lsmod|grep iw
iwlmvm                184162  0 
mac80211              582807  1 iwlmvm
iwlwifi               161370  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211              447796  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwlmvm
```

for each module you can see details with `modinfo <modulename>`

You find your device name and ID with `lspci` (or `lsusb`) for example:

```
$ lspci|grep -i wireless
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 6b)
```

then search for the device-id string **7260** in the details of the loaded modules, in this case you succeed with:

```
$ modinfo iwlwifi|grep 7260
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode
```

then locate the firmware-file with

```
$ locate  iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode
```

Comment: If you only look for the driver of your wireless-card, you can also use `nm-tool |grep Driver` to get the module

Answer (score 1):

You can quickly list all flags that were used during kernel compilation using:

```
cat /boot/config-`uname -r`
```

On a 14.04 system, the Intel 7260 firmware is provided by the `linux-firmware` package, you can check its [filelist](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/all/linux-firmware/filelist).

Comment: And how do I find out, which [wireless firmware](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi#Firmware) is installed? I have an Intel 7260

Comment: @rubo77: I've updated my answer. You should have the firmware installed in `/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260*`

Comment: If you didn't have the firmware installed, your 7260 wouldn't work _at all_.

Comment: @rubo77: Could you please consider accepting this answer? I think it covers your question. Thanks.

Comment: It is correct that my kernel uses linux-firmware, But can you please explain, How you come to the conclusion? I would like to understand the concept behind this, so next time I wonder which device uses which module

Comment: @rubo77 Many firmware images are provided by the `linux-firmware` package which is installed by default (See the 14.04 [Manifest](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.manifest))

Comment: I checked... Now i wonder why my card uses the -8 version although there is provided a -9 version already for my wireless card